# "SIMPLE" Java Facebook Login

Tags: java, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-sdk-4.0, restfb

I'm working on a tiny **Java Desktop project**. Basically, I need to connect my users through their **Facebook** accounts, and once validated, I'd like to retrieve some of their **public information** *(name, email, birthday)*...

I've been doing heavy research regarding this, but the more i read, the more complicated it gets. And there were many points were I got so confused that I just wanted to slam my head through my screen :D

Anyway...

1- I understand that I'd need a **Facebook SDK** *(I'm using restFB)*

2- Create an App on Facebook

3- Request permissions

4- Get User Access Token

5- Retrieve required data *(name, email, birthday)*

One thing I dont understand, do I have to embed some form of **Webbrowser** in my Java app so that I can continue with the Facebook login process or can it be done through **RestFB**? and Unfortunately, RestFB doesnt explain nearly enough how to login a user, and when i found something close enough the user was hardcoded, but what if I want to register a new user everytime?

This is all i"ve got for now regarding the Login process:

```
AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken("471150563090234", "97514014f41b3c1e7f5b697ab5708dec");
String token=accessToken.getAccessToken();
DefaultFacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(token);
```

**ANY** kind of help would be greatly appreciated!! Also, Where does **OAuth** fit in all this, i feel that this is the part I'm missing :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

1. Use an embedded webbrowser. Depending on your app, they framework you use and so on this is no fun and a bit complicated to explain in some sentences. It is very specific and highly depends on how you app is working.
2. The easier way is to use a device access token. You have you user to open a provided url in his/hers browser and enter a code you show in your app. Your application has to poll Facebook as long as the user completed the authentication process or until a timeout occurs.

Have a look at the restfb documentation here: http://restfb.com/documentation/#access-token-device

and the device login explanation at Facebook here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices